# Set forks for one task in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have one task in my playbook that I want to run on only one host at a time. The rest of the tasks I want to honor the --forks option. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Yes checkout [rolling updates](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size)

specifically you can add a "serial: x" parameter for a play where x is the number of forks

Comment: This isn't quite what I wanted. I want to limit the number of parallel executions for just 1 task, not the whole playbook.

Comment: It's not for the whole playbook.  The serial parameter is on per play basis.  A play consists of one or more tasks.  Just put the hosts you want to serialize execution for in a separate play.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible by using the [`throttle` keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#term-131):

> Limit number of concurrent task runs on task, block and playbook level. This
> is independent of the forks and serial settings, but cannot be set higher than
> those limits. For example, if forks is set to 10 and the throttle is set to 15,
> at most 10 hosts will be operated on in parallel.

Example:

```
---

- hosts: all
  tasks:
      - name: wait in parallel
        command: sleep 20
      - name: wait  in serial
        command: sleep 30
        throttle: 1
```

The `throttle` keyword is available in Ansible [since version 2.9](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blame/v2.9.0/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.9.rst#L35).

Answer (score 2):

In the glossary of terms documentation for Ansible there's this paragraph

> #### Rolling Update
>
> The act of addressing a number of nodes in a group N at a time to
>   avoid updating them all at once and bringing the system offline. For
>   instance, in a web topology of 500 nodes handling very large volume,
>   it may be reasonable to update 10 or 20 machines at a time, moving on
>   to the next 10 or 20 when done. The serial: keyword in an Ansible
>   [playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html?highlight=serial#term-playbooks) control the size of the rolling update pool. The default is
>   to address the batch size all at once, so this is something that you
>   must opt-in to. OS configuration (such as making sure config files are
>   correct) does not typically have to use the rolling update model, but
>   can do so if desired.

Using the `--forks=X` along with `serial:` playbook constructs it's not possible to 
limit a single task to run sequentially. That's because the `serial:` keyword is only applicable to playbooks. Your only recourse here is to split your tasks up into 2 playbooks and limit the entire play which includes the task you want to run sequentially to `serial: 1`.

#### Example

```
$ cat helloansible.yml
---
- hosts: all
  serial: 1

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "hello ansible - serial"

- hosts: all

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "hello ansible - batched"
```

When I run this against an inventory you'll see the 1st playbook iterate over each host in the inventory:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory/lab helloansible.yml -l server*

PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server-01a.lab1.mydom.local]

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server-01a.lab1.mydom.local] => {
    "msg": "hello ansible - serial"
}

PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server-01b.lab1.mydom.local]

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server-01b.lab1.mydom.local] => {
    "msg": "hello ansible - serial"
}

PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server-redis-01a.lab1.mydom.local]

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server-redis-01a.lab1.mydom.local] => {
    "msg": "hello ansible - serial"
}

PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server-redis-01b.lab1.mydom.local]

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server-redis-01b.lab1.mydom.local] => {
    "msg": "hello ansible - serial"
}

PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server-redis-01c.lab1.mydom.local]

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server-redis-01c.lab1.mydom.local] => {
    "msg": "hello ansible - serial"
}
```

Whereas in the 2nd playbook that runs:

```
PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server-01b.lab1.mydom.local]
ok: [server-redis-01a.lab1.mydom.local]
ok: [server-redis-01c.lab1.mydom.local]
ok: [server-redis-01b.lab1.mydom.local]
ok: [server-01a.lab1.mydom.local]

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server-01a.lab1.mydom.local] => {
    "msg": "hello ansible - batched"
}
ok: [server-01b.lab1.mydom.local] => {
    "msg": "hello ansible - batched"
}
ok: [server-redis-01a.lab1.mydom.local] => {
    "msg": "hello ansible - batched"
}
ok: [server-redis-01b.lab1.mydom.local] => {
    "msg": "hello ansible - batched"
}
ok: [server-redis-01c.lab1.mydom.local] => {
    "msg": "hello ansible - batched"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
server-01a.lab1.mydom.local : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
server-01b.lab1.mydom.local : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
server-redis-01a.lab1.mydom.local : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
server-redis-01b.lab1.mydom.local : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
server-redis-01c.lab1.mydom.local : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: It's possible with the `throttle` feature that is available since Ansible 2.9 ([cf. my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61046187/427158)).

Answer (score 0):

use throttle option that allowed number of fork per task that different than defined in command line. Option available only in ansible 2.9