# Limit ansible playbook task concurrency

Tags: concurrency, download, ansible

I'm updating several hosts with ansible at the same time, however I have a limitation...

I have to download artifacts from a common repository with no more than 3 simultaneous downloads!

The current solution I have is to limit the whole playbook to max three concurrent tasks

```
strategy: linear
serial: 3
```

Is it possible to limit concurrency only for particular task step rather than the whole playbook?

Comment: Related question: [Set forks for one task in ansible playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33675888/427158)

Answer (score 2):

There's no direct way. Only workarounds like `run_once` loop with `delegate_to` or multiplying the task with loop and executing only one item per host.

See issue [#12170](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/12170), which is closed with "won't fix" status for details.

`delegate_to` loop:

```
- mytask: ..
  delegate_to: "{{item}}"
  run_once: true
  # many diff ways to make the loop
  with_inventory_hostnames: all
```

multiplied task:

```
- name: target task
  debug: msg="Performing task on {{ inventory_hostname }}, item is {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ play_hosts }}"
  when: "hostvars[item].inventory_hostname == inventory_hostname"
```

Comment: Very useful reference to the official ansible repo discussion for this topic! Still those proposed examples I understand execute one step after the other rather than, as asked 3 each time.

Comment: Yes, but you can construct when statement to run several items at once, like taking modulus of current host's index in play_hosts or something like that.

Comment: Yeah, need to try this and see how clean is at the end:)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to only limit the concurrency of a certain task.

You just need to add the [`throttle` keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#term-131) to your download task.

Example:

```
- name: Download payload.tar.gz
  get_url:
    url: https://example.com/path/payload.tar.gz
    dest: /mnt/scratch/payload.tar.gz
    mode: '0640'
  throttle: 3
```

Note that `throttle` was introduced in [Ansible 2.9](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blame/v2.9.0/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.9.rst#L35).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to previous comments and [#12170](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/12170) I have come with my proposal, which still is not working as desired for the download case.

Notice that 2 is the maximum number of concurrent tasks executions desired.

```js
- name: Download at ratio three at most
  win_get_url:
    url: http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/100MB.zip
    dest: c:/ansible/100MB.zip
    force: yes
  with_sequence: start=0 end={{ (( play_hosts | length ) / 2 ) | round (0, 'floor') | int }}
  when: "(( ansible_play_batch.index(inventory_hostname) % (( play_hosts | length ) / 2 )) | round) == (item | int)"
```

While this will match the `when` on each iteration only if for certain hosts I still can see all the server performing the download at the same time.

Another way of testing it is with debug a message and a add a delay between iterations. This way is clear that only two are executed at each iterations.

```js
- debug:
    msg: "Item {{ item }} with modulus {{ (( ansible_play_batch.index(inventory_hostname) % (( play_hosts | length ) / 2 )) | round) }}"
  with_sequence: start=0 end={{ (( play_hosts | length ) / 2 ) | round (0, 'floor') | int }}
  loop_control:
    pause: 2
  when: "(( ansible_play_batch.index(inventory_hostname) % (( play_hosts | length ) / 2 )) | round) == (item | int)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a case of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Why not download the files once to your controller, and then use the `copy` task to fan out from the controller to each host?

(I guess bandwidth concerns between your controller and hosts may cause issues for large files, but it's probably not going to be much different to limiting the download to 3 hosts anyway.)

Comment: Not really. Your approach doesn't scale and easily gets cumbersome or doesn't work depending on the concrete download task (e.g. download via a package manager involving dependency resolution, large host inventory, controller has a slow connection, firewalls, volume limits, etc.). Besides, [one can directly solve this with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63474578/427158).

Answer (score -2):

You can override `forks` variable in `ansible.cf`. default value is 5.

ansible.cf

```
[defaults]
forks = 3
```

[More info](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#forks)

Comment: Thanks, interesting setting, but this I understand will limit the whole process. My requirement is to execute everything in parallel except when downloading an artifact as too many parallel downloads affects the whole platform.