# Can ansible-playbook be run node wise?

Tags: ansible

I want every task of the ansible-playbook to be executed on one node before moving on to the second node. Is there any way to do the same on ansible?  I am able to do the same if I run playbook as Rundeck Job, but I was wondering if playbook provides such functionality for its CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you just need to play with the `serial` option and set in to 1 in your play.

**References**:

- [Ansible Doc - Playbooks Delegation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html)
- [Ansible Doc - Playbooks Strategies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html)
- [Similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675888/set-forks-for-one-task-in-ansible-playbook)